# Codeigniter Joining 4 Tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, codeigniter

I am stuck in generating SQL statement for joining tables.

Basically I have 4 tables. And there are 2 tables with foreign key. Table Sequence is connected to Product table and Region Table. And Distribution table is connected to sequence table.

Table Products.

id | product_desc

Table Region.

id | region_desc

Table Sequence.

id | product_id | region_id

Table Distributions

id | sequence_id | sales | distribution_fee

My Model Code:

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('distributions'); 
$this->db->join('sequence', 'sequence.id = distributions.sequence_id', 'left');
$this->db->join('sequence', 'sequence.product_id=products.product_no'); //Generates Error
$this->db->join('sequence', 'sequence.region_id=regions.id'); // Generates Error
$this->db->order_by('distributions.id','asc');         
$query = $this->db->get(); 
if($query->num_rows() != 0){
   return $query->result_array();
} else {    
  return false;
}
```

Any solutions? It would be high appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you dont join products or regions tables, but you are referencing them

Comment: what do you mean by referencing them? Sequence table is the sequence of product being delivered in a region.

Comment: ill write a response

Comment: Sample records for sequence table.. 

http://prntscr.com/507qh3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

youre not referencing `regions` and `products` tables

try with something like this:

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('distributions'); 
$this->db->join('sequence', 'sequence.id = distributions.sequence_id', 'left');
$this->db->join('products', 'sequence.product_id=products.product_no');
$this->db->join('regions', 'sequence.region_id=regions.id');
$this->db->order_by('distributions.id','asc');         
$query = $this->db->get(); 
if($query->num_rows() != 0){
   return $query->result_array();
} else {    
   return false;
}
```

Comment: oh wow! I never thought it would be that easy! lol . It works as I expected! Thanks!

Comment: @JeffreyBugahod no problem. When you make a join all tables you reference have to be in the query